# не получается обновить массив в двойном вложанном в массиве node.js mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

у меня есть струтура данных похожа на

```
"details": [
    {
      "color": "#000000",
      "size": [
        "1, 2, 3"
      ],
      "img": [
        "images\\2022-10-02T06-40-29.608Z_ds.jfif"
      ],
      "detailStatus": 1,
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6339325d253533794fc54e9d"
      }
    }
  ],
```

их может быть несколько. хочу заменить img при входе данных если оно происходит, следующим образом

```
const productDetailsSave = async(req, res) =>{
  try {
    const _id = req.body._id
    const detailIndex = Number(req.body.index)
    let {color, size, detailStatus} = req.body
    let product = await Product.findById({_id})
    let image = []
    let {img} = req.files
    if(img){
      img.forEach(images =>{
        image.push(images.path)
      })
      product.details.forEach((details, index) =>{
        if(detailIndex == index){
          details.img.forEach(images =>{
            if(fs.existsSync(images)){
              fs.unlinkSync(images)
            }
          })
        }
      })
      product.details[detailIndex] = {color, size, detailStatus, img: image}
    } else{
      product.details[detailIndex] = {color, size, detailStatus: detailStatus || 0}
    }
    await Product.findByIdAndUpdate({_id}, product).lean()
    res.redirect(`/product/info/${_id}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

if вроде бы отрабатывает свою функцию корректно, при входе данных заменяет старые на новые так же удаляя старый файл с последубщей заменой. но при входе в else когда я пытаюсь обновить все данные (size, color, detailStatus), всё кроме самого img где нет входа данных для img оно на выходе даёт пустой массив img с удалением его из базы данных и новый id для массива details, что очень не корректно в таком случае. не могу понять где логика пошла не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

ошибку решил следующим образом передал всё по отдельности в else:

```
product.details[detailIndex].color = color
product.details[detailIndex].size = size
product.details[detailIndex].detailStatus = detailStatus || 0
```